# TargetFrameworkVersion 'v4.5.1' not supported by this toolset (ToolsVersion: 4.0)

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, mono, visual-studio-code

When trying to open a console project using .NET 4.5.1 in Visual Studio Code on Linux Mint using Mono version 4.0.2 the following warning(s) are shown in the Output Window:

> /home/freeman/Projects/SleepyThread/SleepyThread/SleepyThread.csproj:
>   warning : Project has unknown ToolsVersion '14.0'. Using the default
>   tools version '4.0' instead.
>
> /home/freeman/Projects/SleepyThread/SleepyThread/SleepyThread.csproj
>   (default targets) ->
>   [WARNING:OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem]
>   TargetFrameworkVersion 'v4.5.1' not supported by this toolset
>   (ToolsVersion: 4.0).
>   /home/freeman/Projects/SleepyThread/SleepyThread/SleepyThread.csproj
>   /usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets(0,0): Warning:
>   TargetFrameworkVersion 'v4.5.1' not supported by this toolset
>   (ToolsVersion: 4.0).

`dnvm list` output:

> - 1.0.0-beta5          mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      default

Regarding the close vote: I forgot to ask the actual question but I thought it is pretty obvious that the question is how to fix the warning(s).

Comment: Post whatever you learned as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: @LexLi Moved the answers to the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the ToolsVersion to 4.0 in the *.csproj file removes the warning:

```
Project has unknown ToolsVersion '14.0'
```

Downgrading the project settings from `.NET 4.5.1` to `.NET 4.5` removes the warning:

```
TargetFrameworkVersion 'v4.5.1' not supported by this toolset ToolsVersion: 4.0
```

Comment: This only works if your project doesn't care about the ToolsVersion or the .NET version.